# Float moved to next page even though theres enough space

Tags: floats, formatting

Two floats are giving me trouble. Together, they would fit comfortably on a page with enough space for some text and yet, if theres so few as one line of text on the page, the second Float will be moved to the next page:

[image]

Here's the same page with no text:

[image]

As you can see, there a huge amount of white space between the floats, more that enough to acommodate the text and yet, it won't fit.

[image]

Here's an example from the next page, where the text fits snugly around the float. It seems to me that two floats can't be right next to each other? I'm not quite sure what of the Latex source is needed if any for someone to figure this out, I will provide it as needed. The figures are using `[htb]`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This could depend on many factors, the main one being the class you're using.

Comment: Thank you! The document class is `\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,openright,11pt]{book}` as per the template I'm using.

Comment: `[htb]` stops the figures being placed on a page on their own, as you have removed `p` so it is not enough that the two figures fit, they have to fit and allow some text from the page.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I think you misunderstand or I haven't expressed the issue quite clearly enough. I don't want the figures to have their own page, I want the text to be on the same page as both figures. If I remove `[htb]`, the result is the same as the first screenshot, except that the figure is now at the top of the page.

Comment: It's hard to explain what you need to change as you have provided no example code, but by removing `p` you force the figures to go on text pages not float pages, (unless flushed out by `\clearpage` or the end of the document) by default in `book` at least `20%` of a text page has to be text so without seeing the text it is impossible to say whether it should fit or not. `[!htbp]` would give it a better chance of fitting.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `[!htb]` did it! I didn't know the 20%-part. Feel free to post that as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @Marv You should read https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat

Comment: In the post by quoted by Fran, the important values are ``\topfraction``, ``\bottomfraction``, ``\dbltopfraction``, and ``\textfraction`` that you would  fruitfully``\renewcommand``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per @DavidCarlisle, using `[!htb]` fixed the issue for me.